# Can uiautomator running on API 19's emulator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I use below dependency to add uiautomator and write a simple test case. But I found test not found on Android API 19's emulator. Any one know why?

`androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0"`

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you're facing? The question has limited information about the problem.

Comment: UI Automator works on API 18 or higher, so this is not the problem. Please post your test class and the error message.